# Difficulty while parsing JSONObject(Android)

Tags: parsing, arrays, json

I have following JSON Object(Actually, I am not sure if it is an array or object), but I am getting difficulties while parsing it.

```
[{"id":5633,"name":"Qatar tərtibçisi"},{"id":5635,"name":"Mühəndis17.07.2013(for testing purpose)"},{"id":5639,"name":"Elektrik qaz qaynaqçısı"},{"id":5660,"name":"Mühəndis (musabiqe merheleleri test Fuad)"},{"id":5728,"name":"Dülgər"}]
```

I wrote following piece of code to get name(no idea which one). However, I am getting the whole JSONObject back as response.

```
 httpTransport.call(TRANSPORT_CALL, envelope);

 //Get response
 response = envelope.getResponse().toString();
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
 response = jObj.getString("name");
```

Comment: java (I need to parse it for the use in android app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
   String name = row.getString("name");
}
```